# My linked lists program works, but it wont show all of the list

Tags: c++

My linked lists program works, but it wont show all of the list

here is my code
When the user enters a name and contribution it stores it in the list.  When i print out the list only the last name that the user entered showed.  I think its in my AddToList function is the problem  Thanks

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct PersonRec
{
    char aName[20];
    //string aName;
    int aBribe;
    PersonRec* link;
};


class PersonList
{

private:
    PersonRec *head;
    bool IsEmpty();


public:
    PersonList();
    ~PersonList();
    void AddToList();
    void ViewList();

};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "personlist.h"

PersonList::PersonList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

PersonList::~PersonList()
{
    PersonRec *current, *temp;
    current = head;
    temp = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->link;
        delete temp;
        temp = current;
    }
}


bool PersonList::IsEmpty()
{
    //PersonRec *p;

    if(head == NULL)//it has no nodes head will poin to NULL
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        //p = head;
        return false;
    }
}


void PersonList::AddToList()
{
    PersonRec *p;


    head = new PersonRec();   

    //if(head == NULL)
    //{
    if(!IsEmpty())
    {
        //head = new PersonRec();

        cout<<"Enter the person's name: ";
        cin.getline(head->aName, 20);
        //cin>>head->aName;
        cout<<"Enter the person's contribution: ";
        cin>>head->aBribe;
        //head->link = NULL;
        //}
    }    

    else
    {
        p = head;
        while(p->link != NULL)
            p = p->link;
        p->link = new PersonRec();
    }


}//end function

void PersonList::ViewList()
{
    PersonRec *p;
    p = head;

    if(IsEmpty())
    {
        cout<<"List is Empty "<<endl;
    }

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->aName<<" "<<"$"<<p->aBribe<<endl;
        p = p->link;
    }

}

#include <iostream>
#include "personlist.h"

using namespace std;

int displayMenu (void);
void processChoice(int, PersonList&);

int main()
{
    int num;

    PersonList myList;
    do 
    {
        num = displayMenu();
        if (num != 3)
            processChoice(num, myList);
    } while (num != 3);

    return 0;
}

int displayMenu(void)
{
    int choice;
    cout << "\nMenu\n";
    cout << "==============================\n\n";
    cout << "1. Add student to waiting list\n";
    cout << "2. View waiting list\n";
    cout << "3. Exit program\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    cin.ignore();
    return choice;
}

void processChoice(int choice, PersonList& p)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: p.AddToList();
        break;
    case 2: p.ViewList();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: It works (apart from when it does not). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it: `head` is a pointer to the first item in your list, and the first thing you do in `AddToList()` is:

```
head = new PersonRec();
```

What do you *think* is going to happen to the *current* list when you overwrite `head` in this manner?

Don't change `head` until you're ready. The basic pseudo-code would be:

```
newnode = new PersonRec;             # Don't overwrite head yet.
# Populate newnode with payload.
newnode-> next = head                # Put current list at end.
head = newnode                       # Now you can change it.
```

That's if you wanted the new node at the start of the list. If you want it at the end, it's a little more complicated since you either have to:

- traverse the list looking for the last node so you can append the new node to it; or
- keep a pointer to the last node as well, to avoid traversal.

But the detail remains the same: *don't* destroy your head pointer until such time as you have the current list accessible by some other means.

---

I should mention that, based on your commented out code in `AddToList()`, you appear to be very close. Setting `head` *should* be done in the case where `isEmpty()` is true. But you appear to have commented that out and moved the `head = new ...` bit to *outside/before* the `if` statement. Not sure exactly what happened there with your thought processes.

It looks like what you tries to do was along the lines of:

```
if isEmpty:
    head = new PersonRec;
    p = head
else:
    p = head
    while p->next != NULL:
        p = p->next
    p->next = new PersonRec;
    p = p->next

# Here, p is a pointer to the new node (head or otherwise)
# and the list is stable

p-> payload/link = whatever/null
```

That last line is also important, and your code doesn't seem to do it in all cases (ie, other than when you're creating the initial node in the list).

---

Making that a little less language-agnostic would give you something like (untested):

```
void PersonList::AddToList() {
    PersonRec *p;

    if(!IsEmpty()) {
        p = head = new PersonRec();
    } else {
        p = head;
        while (p->link != NULL)
            p = p->link;
        p->link = new PersonRec();
        p = p->link;
    }

    cout << "Enter the person's name: ";
    cin.getline (p->aName, 20);

    cout << "Enter the person's contribution: ";
    cin >> p->aBribe;

    p->link = NULL;
}
```

Comment: for my Addtolist function i put   void PersonList::AddToList()
{
    PersonRec *p;
 PersonRec *newnode;
 
 head = new PersonRec();   
 newnode = new PersonRec();
 //if(head == NULL)
 //{
  if(!IsEmpty())
  {
  //head = new PersonRec();
  
     cout<<"Enter the person's name: ";
  cin.getline(head->aName, 20);
  //cin>>head->aName;
        cout<<"Enter the person's contribution: ";
        cin>>head->aBribe;
  newnode->link = head;
  head = newnode;
 //}
  } 
 
 else
 {
  p = head;
  while(p->link != NULL)
   p = p->link;
  p->link = new PersonRec();
 }
 

}//end function

Comment: @Masoman, it's a little hard to read code in comment boxes but you're _still_ overwriting `head` in all cases, not just for the one when you start the list. That's your problem. Look at the pseudo-code (and _understand_ it) then try to convert that to C.

Comment: when you say dont overwrite head = new PersonRec(); you mean remove it before the isemtpy()?

Comment: @Masoman: Yes, you should only overwrite head if you currently have an empty list (inside the `if`). Otherwise, you need to leave it alone and tack your new node onto the end of the current list. And you need to store the payload in _both_ cases.

Comment: im also confused with this line  what is this for?  p-> payload = whatever   Thanks

Comment: @Masoman, it's the bit that stores the payload. In your case, you only do it in the `if` bit but it needs to be done in both the `if` and the `else` bit or, as in my pseudo-code, after the entire `if` statement. It's basically storing your name and contribution into the new node.

Comment: Your psedu-code, you have this if isEmpty:
    head = new PersonRec;
    p = head
else:
    p = head
    while p->next != NULL:
        p = p->next
    p->next = new PersonRec;
    p = p->next              where should i put the user input before the isemtpy function?

Comment: @Masoman, see the C++ snippet at the end for one way to do it. We should probably stop the comments now since they're not really meant as a conversation system (SO complains if too many comments show up). If you still have a problem after reading the answer as it stands now and trying to implement it, another question with the changed code may be a good idea.

Comment: I got it working, I had to create a current PersonRec object to go through the list